# Xml for txt file records

Tags: c#, xslt

I am having a scenario to push the text records to db to track some information on an individual.

My text file contains the data as shown below:

```
logonID|agentName|modify|exception|start|stop|externalID        
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Break|01:45|02:00|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Break|06:10|06:25|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Lunch|03:45|04:30|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|00:00|01:45|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|02:00|03:45|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|04:30|06:10|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|06:25|08:30|USWMAJ43
```

Now i need to create an XML for Break,Lunch and open(number of open for a record may vary about 5 to 6 entries) as:

```
<info>
<break>
<break_1>01:45-02:00</break_1>
<break_2>06:10-06:25</break_1>
</break>
<lunch>03:45-04:30</lunch>
<open>
<open_1>00:00-01:45</open_1>
<open_2>02:00-03:45</open_2>
<open_3>04:30-06:10</open_3>
<open_4>06:25-08:30</open_4>
</open>
</info>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your solution? You are more likely to get some help if you state your attempts rather than a development request.

Comment: Actually i was inserting the whole txt records as it was in file...But while retrieving and displaying the details of an individual its was difficult for me.. Any help would be helpful...

Comment: Start by having a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205089/is-xslt-good-approach-to-convert-text-to-xml-structure#8207251), which explains about converting text to xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## XSLT

To use the xslt you pass the file location to pText parameter, for example `file:///C:/data.txt` :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pText" />
    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vText" select="unparsed-text($pText)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLines" select="tokenize($vText, '\r?\n')[position() > 1][normalize-space()]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <info>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$vLines" group-by="tokenize(.,'\|')[4]">
                <xsl:variable name="vKey" select="translate(current-grouping-key(), $uppercase, $smallcase)"/>
                <xsl:element name="{$vKey}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:variable name="vValues" select="tokenize(.,'\|')"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:element name="{$vKey}_{$vPos}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat($vValues[5],'-',$vValues[6])"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </info>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input:**

```
logonID|agentName|modify|exception|start|stop|externalID        
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Break|01:45|02:00|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Break|06:10|06:25|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Lunch|03:45|04:30|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|00:00|01:45|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|02:00|03:45|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|04:30|06:10|USWMAJ43
14051286759|Jacks, Monica|1373477063|Open|06:25|08:30|USWMAJ43
```

**Output:**

```
<info>
    <break>
        <break_1>01:45-02:00</break_1>
        <break_2>06:10-06:25</break_2>
    </break>
    <lunch>
        <lunch_1>03:45-04:30</lunch_1>
    </lunch>
    <open>
        <open_1>00:00-01:45</open_1>
        <open_2>02:00-03:45</open_2>
        <open_3>04:30-06:10</open_3>
        <open_4>06:25-08:30</open_4>
    </open>
</info>
```

## C#

*[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521064/passing-parameters-to-xslt-stylesheet-via-net#1521090) and [Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp#34095)*

```
XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
argsList.AddParam("pText", "", "file:///C:/data.txt");
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(myXmlFile) ;
XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load(myStyleSheet);
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("result.html",null);
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc,argsList,myWriter);
```