# XSLT 2.0 file reading

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am getting this error while reading.txt file through `XSLT 2.0` -

```
ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(unparsed-text, [parameter-ref(text-uri/reference), parameter-ref(text-encoding/reference)])'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile StyleSheet'.
```

Trying to process using javax.xml.transform.Transformer.

Any feedback would be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the XSLT stylesheet you are having problems with. In particular the line calling "unparsed-text". Thanks!

Comment: @Tim ,Thanks. Please look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205089/is-xslt-good-approach-to-convert-text-to-xml-structure. good example, but .txt is accessed inside xslt. i am trying the same xslt in my java class.

Comment: @cooper, if you want to use XSLT 2.0 then you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9. Are you doing that? Or are you trying to compile an XSLT 2.0 with the Oracle JRE's built-in XSLT processor? That only supports XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Martin, Thanks. Can we avoid passing file path to unparsed-text() as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205089/is-xslt-good-approach-to-convert-text-to-xml-structure, in order to pass txt-file path through program.

Comment: @cooper, an XSLT program can take external parameters, simply put an `<xsl:param name="my-file" select="'file.txt'"/>` as a top level element, then check the API of your XSLT processor on how to set that parameter from your code (e.g. Java) before running a transformation.